# fluentd regex pattern not match error for NGINX logs

Tags: regex, nginx, fluentd

I've setup fluentd to parse nginx access logs since I've added some extra fields to the logs I cannot use the nginx format. My configuration is:

```
   <source>
    @type tail
    @id service_www_accesslog
    path /var/log/containers/imager-nginx*.log
    pos_file /var/log/imager-nginx-containers.log.pos
    tag influxdb.*
    read_from_head true
    format /(?<host>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] \[Cache:(?<cache>\b\w+\b)\] "(?<CSMethod>\b\w+\b) (?<CSURIStem>(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9$.+!*'(){},~:;=@#%&_\-]*)+) (?<request>.*?)" (?<SCStatus>(?:(?:(?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+)))))) (?<image_size>(?:(?:(?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+)))))) "(?<referer>.*?)" "(?<user_agent>.*?)" "(?<xforward>.*?)" (?<request_time>(?:(?:(?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+)))))) (?<upstream_response>.*?) (?<upstream_connect>.*?) (?<upstream_header>.*)/
    time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
    @log_level debug
  </source>
```

sample of the log:

```
10.244.1.0 [07/Dec/2018:16:51:49 +0000] [Cache:MISS] "GET /10e8cd74-94ec-4652-a5c9-d5df1110b9eb/475/400/60/false/blah.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 60435 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36" "172.23.8.123" 0.162 0.160 0.001 0.151
```

In the fluentd output I get an error:

```
2018-12-07 16:51:50 +0000 [warn]: #0 [service_www_accesslog] pattern not match: "{\"log\":\"10.244.1.0 [07/Dec/2018:16:51:49 +0000] [Cache:MISS] \\\"GET /10e8cd74-94ec-4652-a5c9-d5df1110b9eb/475/400/60/false/blah.jpg HTTP/1.1\\\" 200 60435 \\\"-\\\" \\\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36\\\" \\\"172.23.8.123\\\" 0.162 0.160 0.001 0.151\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2018-12-07T16:51:49.224406444Z\"}"
```

I've tested the regex using several regex testers and it does have the correct output, I've also tested using [Fluentular](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/) and used the output for the config.

I'm not sure where to go from here in debugging this error. Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Please post a clear input sample and desired output .

Comment: @PedroLobito not sure what extra information I should add? There is a log entry sample provide and I would expect no error.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is correct. Issue is you are using deprecated [format](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/in_tail#format) parameter. Instead you will need to use [parser](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/parser-plugin-overview) plugin and there is built-in [nginx](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/parser_nginx) parser where you can set your expression. Below will be your updated fluent.conf and it works fine parsing your input.

```
<source>
  @type tail
  @id service_www_accesslog
  path /var/log/containers/imager-nginx*.log
  pos_file /var/log/imager-nginx-containers.log.pos
  tag influxdb.*
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
   @type nginx
   expression /(?<host>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] \[Cache:(?<cache>\b\w+\b)\] "(?<CSMethod>\b\w+\b) (?<CSURIStem>(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9$.+!*'(){},~:;=@#%&_\-]*)+) (?<request>.*?)" (?<SCStatus>(?:(?:(?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+)))))) (?<image_size>(?:(?:(?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+)))))) "(?<referer>.*?)" "(?<user_agent>.*?)" "(?<xforward>.*?)" (?<request_time>(?:(?:(?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+)))))) (?<upstream_response>.*?) (?<upstream_connect>.*?) (?<upstream_header>.*)/
   time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
  </parse>
  @log_level debug
</source>
```